# Forward button not working when using history and pushState/currentState on modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history, html5-history

I'm using history and pushState/currentState to:

1. Change the URL when the modal is fired.
2. If back button or modal close button is pushed, close the modal and
   go back to the previous URL.
3. If modal is fired, closed, and the forward button is pushed, re-open
   the modal and go to the modal URL.

All is working EXCEPT 3. I have this JS in there but it doesn't seem to work:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (e) {
        var state = history.state;
        // back button pressed. close popup
        if (!state) {
            $(".modal").css({ "display": "none" });
            $('body').css('position', 'relative');
        }
        else {
            dataModal = $(this).attr("data-modal");
            $("#" + dataModal).css({ "display": "flex" });
            $('body').css('position', 'fixed');
        }
    });
```

[And here is a Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/5j54koab/2/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 apparent issues in your code:

1. `dataModal = $(this).attr("data-modal");`. `this` in this context refers to the `window` object because the `popstate` event is registered on the `window`. The `window` doesn't have a `data-modal` attribute so `dataModal === undefined`
2. You're not saving the modal id anywhere when you `pushState` in the modal trigger event.

**Possible solution**

Try doing something like `history.pushState({dataModal: dataModal}, title, url);` in the modal trigger event. Then in the popstate event you can do `var dataModal = e.state.dataModal` to get the modal id.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.